# How can I change the name of the field in a report (without changing the API name)?

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

How can I change the name of the field in a report (without changing the API name of the field)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to rename the Report columns within Standard Report Types but possible in custom report types.
There is a official documentation for this.

[Check this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315838&type=1&mode=1)